# editing nested resources gives exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have following problem. I'm writting simple blog for learn rails. My project is mostly based on scaffolds. In simplification, I have 2 models: Post and Comment. Post has many comments.

I'm using nested resources:

```
resources :posts do
  resources :comments
end
```

In post's show action i'm listing all post's comments and I have form for creating new comments, and it all works ok. But I have problem when I want to edit comments, I get "NoMethodError in Comments#edit".

```
undefined method `comment_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fe554980ad0>:0x007fe5569fedc0>
Did you mean?  font_path
```

Rails guides doesn't help me.

My code:

in PostController

```
def show
  @comments = @post.comments
  @comment = Comment.new
end
```

in post's view(through comment's partial for listing comments)

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_comment_path(@post, comment)%>
```

in CommentController

```
def edit
end
```

in comment's view

```
<%= render 'form' %>
```

and partial form

```
<%= form_for([@post, @comment]) do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :content %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :content %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This line

```
<%= form_for([@post, @comment]) do |f| %>
```

gives me an exception.

Comment: probably u have somewhere `comment_path`, scaffolding generated for u. so u have to find it.

Comment: Can you show `comments#edit`? And the full error message?

Comment: @AnthonyE code: http://pastebin.com/GVbP2R5T error: http://pastebin.com/2DZqMems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `@post` is nil so `[@post, @comment]` is actually being evaluated as `[nil, @comment]` which is trying to map to the `comments_path` route.

Make sure you assign `@post` in your controller: `@post = Post.find(...)`

Comment: So what is the solution?

Comment: Make sure you assign `@post` in your controller: `@post = Post.find(...)`

Comment: In Post or Comment controller? I have it in Post.

Comment: You'll need it in both if `@post` is called from one of your `Comment` views.